# Deriving the equations of motion of a string from Polyakov action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action, variational-calculus

The Polyakov action  for a string in spacetime $(M, g)$ is

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\eta\lambda}(\sigma)g_{\mu\nu}(x(\sigma))\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma^{\lambda}}$$

And Euler-Lagrange equations for a classical field reads

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^{\rho}}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial \sigma^{\rho}})}-\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} = 0$$

Using the fact that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} = \frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\eta\lambda}(\sigma)\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma^{\lambda}}$, we conclude that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^{\rho}}\biggr(\frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\eta\rho}(\sigma)g_{\mu\alpha}(x(\sigma))\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}}\biggr) - \frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\eta\lambda}(\sigma)\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma^{\lambda}} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma^{\rho}}\sqrt{-\det(h)} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\gamma\beta}(\sigma)\frac{\partial h_{\gamma\beta}}{\partial \sigma^{\rho}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}\Gamma^{\gamma}_{\rho\gamma}$$

$$\begin{align}\biggr(-\frac{T}{4}\sqrt{-\det(h)}\Gamma^{\gamma}_{\rho \gamma}h^{\eta\rho}(\sigma)g_{\mu\alpha}(x(\sigma))\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial\sigma^{\eta}} + \frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}\frac{\partial h^{\eta\rho}}{\partial \sigma^{\rho}}g_{\mu\alpha}(x(\sigma))\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}} &+ \frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\eta\rho}(\sigma)g_{\mu\alpha}(x(\sigma))\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^{\rho}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}}\biggr) - \frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\eta\lambda}(\sigma)\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma^{\lambda}} &= 0\end{align}$$

Does this make any sense?

**Note:** I am looking for a derivation without using Poincaré and Weyl invariance (see section "[Symmetries of the Polyakov Action](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/string1.pdf)" and the comments). Details of the derivation can be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311248/226902), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/423390/226902) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533955/226902), while [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540924/226902) is for the [Nambu-Goto](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17349/226902) action.

Comment: You may find section 2.4.2 here useful: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/fs13/cft/CST2_Reutter.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj0xqTBhNb8AhWfWaQEHRdLABUQFnoECBcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0cnt3viWvbc9YpCX7v5UYF

Comment: Thanks for that reference, although I had hoped for a derivation without using Poincaré and Weyl invariance to make $g$ terms disappear.

Comment: Deane, I took the freedom to link several (I hope useful) questions within your answer. If you come up with a good answer, please post your own answer. Unfortunately, I can not help you more than this because this is not really in my expertise. If I come up with a clear explicit calculation, I will post it.

Comment: If you're allowing for an arbitrary target space metric $g(x(\sigma))$, how can you conlcude that $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x^\mu} = 0$?

Comment: 1. You have made over 30, mostly minor, edits to this question. Please be mindful that every edit bumps the question on the page of active question and try to make your edits few and substantial. 2. One of your edits removed a lot of context and links from the question. Please do not drastically change questions, especially not after they have received an answer.

Comment: Thank you, sure, I'll be paying great attention to that.

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4623577/11127

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\pd}{\partial}$Let's use worldsheet differential forms to make our life easier. So, for example,
$$\d X^\mu(\sigma) = \pd_\alpha X^\mu(\sigma)\; \d\sigma^\alpha.$$
I will also denote the fields by capital $X$; $\left\{\mu,\nu,\ldots\right\}$ will be spacetime indices and $\{\alpha,\beta,\ldots\}$ will be worldsheet indices (whenever necessary), so expressions like $\partial_\alpha$ will mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma^\alpha}$.

With these, the Polyakov action for the fields
$$X^\mu\in\operatorname{Maps}((\Sigma,h)\to(M,g))\cong \Omega^0(\Sigma;M)$$
can be rewritten as
$$S[X] = \frac{T}{2}\int_\Sigma g_{\mu\nu}(X)\ \d X^\mu\wedge \star\, \d X^\nu,$$
where $\star$ is the [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) on $\Sigma$. Note that from the point of view of the worldsheet, $\Sigma$, $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a scalar. It is then easy to just vary the action and get
\begin{align}
0\overset{!}{=} \delta S &= \frac{T}{2}\int_\Sigma \Big(\delta g_{\mu\nu}(X)\ \d X^\mu\wedge \star\, \d X^\nu + 2\,g_{\mu\nu}(X)\ \d\ \delta X^\mu\wedge \star\, \d X^\nu \Big) = \\ 
&= \frac{T}{2}\int_\Sigma \Big(2\, \Gamma^{(g)}_{\mu\nu\lambda}\ \d X^\mu\wedge \star\, \d X^\nu - 2\, \d\big(g_{\mu\lambda}(X)\ \star\, \d X^\mu\big) \Big)\ \delta X^\lambda,
\end{align}
where
$$\Gamma^{(g)}_{\mu\nu\lambda}:=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}(X)}{\partial X^\lambda}+\frac{\partial g_{\mu\lambda}(X)}{\partial X^\nu}-\frac{\partial g_{\lambda\nu}(X)}{\partial X^\mu}\right),$$
are the Christoffel symbols for $g$.

That's the EOM then:
$$ \d\big(g_{\mu\lambda}(X)\ \star\, \d X^\mu\big) -\Gamma^{(g)}_{\mu\nu\lambda}\ \d X^\mu\wedge \star\, \d X^\nu = 0.$$
You can reinstate the definition of the Hodge star and of $\d$ to get a more explicit presentation:
$$ \partial_\alpha\Big(\sqrt{-\det(h)}\, h^{\alpha\beta}\ g_{\mu\lambda}(X(\sigma))\;\partial_\beta X^\mu\Big) - \Gamma_{\mu\nu\lambda}^{(g)} \sqrt{-\det(h)}\, h^{\alpha\beta} \partial_{\alpha}X^\mu \partial_\beta X^\nu = 0.$$

Note that when $(M,g)=(\mathbb{R}^{D},\eta)$ this becomes the usual Polyakov EOM
$$ \partial_\alpha\Big(\sqrt{-\det(h)}\, h^{\alpha\beta}\;\partial_\beta X^\mu\Big) = 0.$$

The last one is simply ($\sqrt{-\det(h)}$ times) the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $(\Sigma,h)$ acting on $X^\lambda$. Using the formula for the variation of the determinant, one can show that [this is equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Gradient,_divergence,_Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator)
$$ \sqrt{-\det(h)} \Big(h^{\alpha\beta} \partial_\alpha \partial_\beta - h^{\alpha\beta}{\Gamma^{(h)}}^\delta_{\alpha\beta}\partial_\delta\Big)X^\mu = 0,$$
where now ${\Gamma^{(h)}}^\cdot_{\cdot\cdot}$ are the *worldsheet* Christoffel symbols.

Comment: @Deane Which last term?

Comment: You don't need a complicated target space for that, then... :)

Comment: @Deane I updated the answer

Comment: And by using your previous suggestion, I came up with: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} = \frac{T}{2}\sqrt{-\det(h)}h^{\eta\lambda}(\sigma)\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \sigma^{\eta}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial \sigma^{\lambda}}$

Comment: Your derivation is wrong, for a simple reason. Your index manipulations are very, very wonky. For example $\eta$ is repeated three times, $\rho$ also three times, so I stopped looking because I couldn't extract any meaning from it and decided to give you my own, correct version. I would advice that you train your index gymnastics really hard before having a go at string theory. The formula in your last comment is correct.

Comment: Thank you @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə , +1 for the extremely useful answer :)

Comment: @Deane That's why you should brush up your special relativity first. For example, your "$\partial_\rho\sqrt{-|h|}$" formula should read $\partial_\alpha\sqrt{-|h|} = \frac12 \sqrt{-|h|} h^{\beta\gamma} \partial_\alpha h_{\beta\gamma}$. Also I would advice you to stick to a convention for your indices. E.g. "greek indices: worldsheet; latin indices: spacetime" or "greek from the beginning: worldsheet; greek from the middle: spacetime" to minimise your confusion.

Comment: @Deane Somewhat. But keep in mind that it's not a great idea to significantly change your question after it has been answered, with input from the answer.

Comment: Deane, please stop modifying this question, you have removed useful references (this website is a "knowledge net", so links to related questions and references are important for users!) and continuously change the details of the calculation. Accept @ɪdɪət strəʊlə answer and if you have other questions make a new specific post.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Is there any additional condition on the maps $X$ you assumed besides being smooth? Because I thought that they should be embeddings, or at least immersions.

Comment: @Geni they are embeddings indeed (but this doesn't affect the answer)